# How to assign value for getter setter variable from Apex test class

Tags: standardcontroller, getter, setter

```
Class A{
    public object obj{get;set;}
}
```

Test Class

```
Class A_Test{
//how to assign value fo obj variable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A aInstance = new A();
aInstance.obj = new Account();
```

I recommend you to take a look into [unit-tests trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) and [Apex basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_intro)

Comment: This doesn't work for Getter Setter variables. it works for normal. my question is not related the test coverage its regarding assigning values from Test class to getter setter variable. this once i tried with get and set methods also. even throw method after passing value also it wont work.

Comment: `This doesn't work for Getter Setter variables.` what do you mean? Show us example of expected and actual outcome

Comment: Sorry Alexander, its works perfectly. i had made some mistake in creation of dummy data in test class. Thanks for the help